# Issues with htaccess URL Rewrite (specific for CPanel type hosting)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd, mod-rewrite

I have an application set up on Apache 2.2 CentOS (with cPanel). I am facing issues with htaccess. I have confirmed that mod_rewrite is working. My .htaccess file is laid out like :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php
```

My webapp folder basically has a file index.php , all URL requests need to be directed through this file.

I tried the following and it seems my .htaccess or httpconf has issues:

1. Removing everything from htaccess still accesses the index.php file (probably default behaviour to look for index.php)
2. I changed the name of index file so that there was no file named index in the application root directory - it threw a 403 .
3. If I comment out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` it throws a 404
4. `Deny from all` throws a 403 as expected
5. With this configuration all other directories (such as those containing CSS/images etc) which do not have their individual htaccess throw a 403 when I try to access them

Possible problem areas

1. htaccess file
2. Virtual Host /Directory configuration in httpd conf
3. Apache User Permission issues on folders(not likely)

What might be the way to figure out what's going wrong and how do I correct it?

**EDIT**

I looked at the server error_log and this is what I found :

```
[Thu Jan 17 07:44:45 2013] [error] [client 182.68.43.96] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/home

[Thu Jan 17 07:44:45 2013][error] [client 182.68.43.96] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/home, referer: http://IP_ADDRESS_HERE/~myapp/myapp/user
```

It is looking for the files in apache htdocs when it is present in an alternate directory . Even so , it should not be looking for a directory called 'user' under myapp , it should be redirected to index.php as per htaccess file . I re wrote the base , now it is looking under the myapp directory , however it still does not execute index.php as it should at every request .

Comment: To further my case , there seems to be a number of Old questions around the same issue  : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582310/problem-with-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite?rq=1
I have gone through the wiki(s) present on SO regarding this but nothing seems to help .

Comment: I think this would be a better fit at webmasters.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to resolve this . The issue is very specific if you are hosting on a VPS along with cpanel or something similar where your files are not in apache's htdocs folder .

The last line of .htaccess should read :

```
RewriteRule . /~cpanel_account_name/app_folder/index.php
```

This helped out a lot : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/